# HTML link with data-method isn't working

Tags: html, angularjs, pugjs

Im trying to create a link in a view of AngularJS application just to send a data-method DELETE.

My route:

```
app.delete('/logout', function(req, res) {
   req.session = null
   res.status(200)
   res.redirect('/')
})
```

My PugJS template:

```
a(ng-href='/logout', data-method='delete', data-confirm='Are you sure?', rel='nofollow')
          span(translate) Logout
```

The HTML generated:

```
<a ng-href="/logout" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" class="" href="/logout">
   <span translate="translate" class="ng-scope">
      <span class="ng-scope">Logout</span>
   </span>
</a>
```

But when I follow the link I receive the follow message:

```
Cannot GET /logout
```

It's looks to me that the data-method isn`t working. Does some one know what is happening?

Thanks for while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are used to use `data-method` with Rails. In AngularJS (or HTML), there is no such thing as `data-method`.

My suggestion is to either write your own directive to send the delete, or to add an action in your controller and use `ng-click` instead.